# Issue setting new Yii2 theme on basic template

Tags: themes, yii2

I have downloaded and set the theme according to the Themefactory site and other SO posts but the theme is just loading as pure html. Meaning that there is no formatting, just text and links.

This is my code in the web.php file in the config directory:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
           'class' => 'yii\web\View',
           'theme' => [
               'class' => 'yii\base\dorian',
               'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => 'themes/dorian'],
               'baseUrl'   => 'themes/dorian'
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'KecrcGLWURmyPrWp3QBgYuOQ21JuCFA1',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
```

Screenshot of file tree: http://prntscr.com/9708gi

Does anyone see anything wrong???

Comment: could be the theme not load the css for path problem .. show your theme layout

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9708gi <<<<< Here it is

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/themes/tf-dorian',

            'pathMap' => [
                '@app/views' => '@app/themes/tf-dorian',
            ],
            'baseUrl' => '@web/',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this and let me know if it doesn't work:

```
'view' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\View',
    'theme' => [
      'class' => 'yii\base\Theme',
      'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => 'themes/tf-dorian'],
      'baseUrl'   => 'themes/tf-dorian'
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I figured it out. The themes directory had to go under the "web"  directory.